# Sending email with Microsoft graph API work account

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Does anyone know how to request permission to send emails using Graph API by an app that runs without a signed-in user?

I have an Azure WebApp with permission to send email using Microsoft Graph.
In the Azure portal (Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> MyApp - API permissions), my app has granted permission for `Mail.Send`( Type: Application : Description: Send mail as any user ).

In the next step, I’m inviting a user from my organization. In Azure Ad the user type is Guest. I receive an email on that account to accept the invitation.
I can log in with that account through the Microsoft login page but the account is managed by my organization – it is not an account created by me.

Using that account with MS Graph explorer I’m able to send an email, but I want to do the same from my application without been logged in. The purpose is to use this account only for sending emails.

I was able to get the access token, use the API and get user basic info, but I get an exception when I'm trying to send an email:

> Code: ResourceNotFound
>
> Message: Resource could not be discovered.

```
// get token
var authContext =
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID);

var result = await authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", new ClientCredential(clientId, secret));

// create graph service
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClientApp =
    new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async(requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);
            }));

// create message obj
//.....

// send email
await graphServiceClientApp.Users["f5521fbc-481e-4e90-9166-33a64eb8f7e9"]
    .SendMail(message, false)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

The user ID like `f5521fbc-481e-4e90-9166-33a64eb8f7e9` is taken from azure portal, in user details there is a Object ID field

Comment: Can you add the details of how you created `authContext`? And also details on how you obtained the User object ID?

Comment: I updated the code sample. The user ID like f5521fbc-481e-4e90-9166-33a64eb8f7e9 is taken from azure portal, in user details there is a Object ID field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sending an email as a user, the user needs to have a mailbox associated with them.

Users without a license that includes Exchange Online, as well as external users (e.g. invited users) will generally not have a mailbox in the tenant, and thus would be unable to send emails.

Comment: I thought that if I'm able to use [MS graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) with that account it will work in azure too. The only difference is that with the Graph explorer samples I have to authenticate with that user first

Comment: When you sign into Graph Explorer using the user's account, it is authenticating against _their_ AAD tenant. When you fetch a token for your app however, you are authenticating against _your_ AAD tenant. They may very well have a mailbox on their tenant, that does not mean they have one on yours.